# Two classes with constructors such that they reference each other?

Tags: .net-3.5, c#-4.0

I have a feeling that this is a code smell, and I could be doing this better, and if that is the case please point it out.

```
class main
{
  void main()
  {
    object A
    object B

    A = new SystemA(ref B)
    B = new SystemB(ref A)
   }
}
class SystemA
{
  SystemB B;
  public SystemA (ref B)
  {
    this.B = B;
  }
}
class SystemB
{
  SystemA A;
  public SystemA (ref A)
  {
    this.A = A;
  }
}
```

Basically I need to initialize two classes with references to each other.

This doesn't work and generates a null reference exception for the class fields in the two child classes when they are later accessed after initialization.

I realize I could probably set these after initialization, but this adds a touch more bloat that I would like to avoid, since I view these assignments as initialization actions.

Comment: The code above doesn't compile. Please post the actual code.

Comment: This requires so much hoop jumping that every time I encounter it I wish to eliminate the creator of such a construct.

Comment: @Brian - these are the hoops to which I am referring. There are tricks to get here (and they suck).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you gave code which actually compiled, I suspect it would just end up with `SystemA` storing a reference to `null` - because that's the value of `B` when you construct `A`.

Having two classes which need a reference to each other is definitely a code smell, but you simply *can't* make them both refer to each other, unless one of them constructs the other and passes in "this", e.g.

```
class SystemA
{
    private readonly SystemB systemB;

    public SystemA()
    {
        systemB = new SystemB(this);
    }
}

class SystemB
{
    private readonly SystemA systemA;

    public SystemB(SystemA systemA)
    {
        this.systemA = systemA;
    }
}
```

Now if you need access to both values afterwards, you could *either* put a property in one of them giving access to the other, or (and this is really nasty) use an `out` parameter in the constructor:

```
public SystemA(out systemB)
{
    systemB = new SystemB(this);
    this.systemB = systemB;
}
```

Then call it as:

```
SystemB b;
SystemA a = new SystemA(out b);
```

**Please don't do this though.**

- It's horrendously complicated
- [It's generally a bad idea to let `this` escape a constructor anyway](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/09/02/don-t-let-this-get-away.aspx)